# Android Populate Listview from JSON (link from edittext)

Tags: android, json, listview

I am new in android and am working with a project that loads data from internet into listview. I got my prototype here: kaleidosblog.com/android-listview-load-data-from-json

So these will be the json links:

- http://www.funtrial.com/christiancepe/announcements/json.php?page=1
- http://www.funtrial.com/christiancepe/announcements/json.php?page=2
- So on..

In my activity, I have my EditText, Button and  ListView.

- Editext will get the url.
- Button will be use to load the json link (from url) to listview
- Listview will display datas

In my current program, it only works on first click of button. So once I entered the first json, it will show the correct data. But when I try to change the json on EditText, still the ListView is populated by the first json. In short, my ListView does not refresh everytime I am changing the link and clicking the button.

What's wrong with this?

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    final EditText searchForm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchForm);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            search = searchForm.getText().toString();
            Download_data download_data = new Download_data((download_complete) MainActivity.this);
            download_data.download_data_from_link(search);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), search, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }

    public void get_data(String data){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray data_array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("announcements");

            for (int i = 0 ; i < data_array.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

                Countries add=new Countries();
                add.name = obj.getString("message");
                add.code = obj.getString("date");

                countries.add(add);

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Download_data.java

```
public class Download_data implements Runnable  {

    public download_complete caller;

    public interface download_complete{
        public void get_data(String data);
    }   

    Download_data(download_complete caller) {         
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    private String link;
    public void download_data_from_link(String link){
        this.link = link;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

     public void run() {
        threadMsg(download(this.link));

     }

     private void threadMsg(String msg) {

         if (!msg.equals(null) && !msg.equals("")) {
             Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
             Bundle b = new Bundle();
             b.putString("message", msg);
             msgObj.setData(b);
             handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
         }
     }


     private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

             String Response = msg.getData().getString("message");

             caller.get_data(Response);

         }
     };
    public static String download(String url) {
         URL website;
         StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
            website = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(
                     connection.getInputStream()));

            response = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                response.append(inputLine);

            in.close();

        } catch (Exception  e) {
            return "";
        }
         return response.toString();
     }
```

ListAdapter.java

```
MainActivity main;

ListAdapter(MainActivity main)
{
    this.main = main;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  main.countries.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView name;
    TextView code;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
    if (convertView == null) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
         holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.name.setText(this.main.countries.get(position).name);
    holder.code.setText(this.main.countries.get(position).code);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the countries list is being added to each time in get_data(), but never cleared out. At the start of get_data, you most likely want to clear the countries list with the following call:

```
countries.clear();
```

Then the data in the countries list will be cleared out, the new downloaded data will be added to the countries list, and then updated in the view when the adapter is notified of the data change.